# Option to make Microsoft Visual Studio accept logic checks/function calls before variable declarations?

Tags: c, visual-studio

If I try to compile this in MVS:

```
void my_fun(int x){
    if(x==0)
        return;

    int y = x;
    y++; 
    ...
}
```

I get an error along the lines of variable `y` being undeclared. However, if I do this everything works fine.

```
void my_fun(int x){
    int y = x;
    y++; 
    if(x==0)
        return;
    ...
}
```

Which is really inconvenient considering that if the logic check returns true then I just want to exit the function anyway without the overhead of declaring variables that will not be used.

Is there a way to change this ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a C89 compiler.  In C89, variable declarations must reside at the beginning of a scope block.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to see if I can change this but cannot find the option. What a strange thing to being a compiler for an older implementation by default.

Comment: @sherrellbc change the extension of the file to `.cpp`, C++ implements most of C89, so you should be ok

Comment: @sherrellbc: There is no option; it is a C89 compiler.  That's all that MS offers. If you want to write C you may want to look into using a different compiler.

Comment: @sherrellbc They have implemented (almost)c99 in the latest visual studio.

Comment: @self.: Yeah, I forgot that they caved and did some things in 2013

Comment: @EdS. I still wouldn't use it for c, but c++ is ok I hear.

Comment: @self.: Me neither.  I use VS for C++ regularly though.

Comment: @sherrellbc: I don't think "use C++" is good advice if the intent is to use/learn C.

Comment: @self: Do you have a link or a reference for this?  My understanding was that MS was never going to support anything past C89 (because you were supposed to move to .Net for everything).  If they changed their minds, that's Big News in my opinion.

Comment: @JohnBode: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx